# Ioun Stone (amber spindle) stacking

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, bonus-type

Ioun Stone (amber spindle) states:

> This stone grants you a +1 resistance bonus on saving throws. The bonuses from multiple amber spindles stack (up to a maximum of a +5 resistance bonus to saving throws).

Flawed Ioun Stone (amber spindle)'s are similar but:

> This stone grants a +1 resistance bonus on saving throws per stone, stacking up to +3 total with other amber spindle ioun stones (flawed or otherwise).

Clearly, if you have one complete stone and two flawed stones, you have a +3 Resistance bonus. However, what if you have more complete stones with your flawed? Can you reach +5 Resistance with 3 flawed and 2 complete stones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

As the flawed Amber Spindle states:

> stacking up to **+3 total** with other amber spindle ioun stones (flawed or otherwise).

Regardless of the amount of Amber Spindles you have of other qualities, the flawed stone will not apply this bonus if the total you already have is +3 or higher.

If you had 2 flawed stones, and 1 full stone, you would have a total of +3.  By adding a second full stone, one of the original flawed stones will then cease to provide this bonus.

Answer (score -3):

It depends in what order the bonuses are applied in.  If you apply the flawed stones first, they work.  If you apply them last, they don't.  There's no definite rule for the order in which bonuses are applied in this case, though generally the last effect gained is applied last, so probably the order you equip them in is what's used.